# Noindex subscriber author page

Tags: php, pages, user-roles, author, noindex

I added the possibility to register on my site (with the role of subscriber), however each registration creates an author page for the user, but I do not want these pages to be indexed, only the pages of authors with roles above.

Something like the code below, but theres no get_user_role function, so i do not know how to get to that result. I would be grateful if anyone could help.

```
<meta name="robots" content="<?php if( is_page('author') ) && get_user_role('subscriber'); {  
    echo "noindex, nofollow";
  }else{
    echo "index, follow";
  } ?>" />
```

Edit:

This is the code of @belinos answer. I put it inside header.php, the problem is that an error appears on the [online site](http://gamersaction.pe.hu/), on localhost it does not appear.

```
<?php $curauth = ( isset( $_GET[ 'author_name' ] ) ) ? get_user_by( 'slug', $author_name ) : get_userdata( intval ($author ) ); 

$auth_data = get_userdata( $curauth->ID ); 

if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $auth_data->roles )) { ?>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/> 
<?php } else { ?>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
<?php } ?>
```

This is the error:

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/u836053643/public_html/wp-content/themes/gamersaction/header.php on line 35

And that is the line 35:

```
if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $auth_data->roles )) { ?>
```

The code works perfectly but is showing this error.

Answer (score 1):

The function you want is `get_userdata()`. Since you need to do this outside the loop, the process is a little less straight-forward.

The first thing you need to do is set up a variable called `$curauth` which is an object that you create by accessing the database by using  the `$_GET[]` superglobal.

```
$curauth = ( isset( $_GET[ 'author_name' ] ) ) ? get_user_by( 'slug', $author_name ) : get_userdata( intval ($author ) );
```

This assigning of `$curauth` must be in your `author.php` file.

After that, we can then use the `get_userdata()` function and feed it the ID from `$curauth`.

```
$auth_data = get_userdata( $curauth->ID );
```

And from there your conditional becomes:

```
if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $auth_data->roles ) ) {
    // No Follow Code
} else {
    // Follow Code
}
```

My advice would be to make this all a function in your `functions.php` file:

```
function author_nofollow( $author ) {

    $auth_id = $author->ID;
    $auth_data = get_userdata( $auth_id );

    if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $auth_data->roles ) ) {
        echo 'noindex, nofollow';
    } else {
        echo 'index, follow';
    }
}
```

Then you would just call it like this:

```
<meta name="robots" content="<?php author_nofollow( $curauth ); ?>">
```

Comment: This is appearing on the online site, in localhost does not appear. Do you know what it can be? Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/u836053643/public_html/wp-content/themes/gamersaction/header.php on line 35. You can see this here http://gamersaction.pe.hu/ . Line 35 is this if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $auth_data->roles )) {

Comment: You're going to have to edit your original post with the code from that page since I cannot see the PHP in context. Or provide a link to pastebin or something. It looks like `$auth_data` or `$curauth` is not being defined properly.

Comment: Edited, please take a look

Comment: `$curauth` needs to be defined in `author.php`.

Comment: I already had it set there, now I removed it from the header and kept only in the author.php and now the subscriber is indexing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @belinus `<meta>` elements must be placed in the `<head>` section of the page to function properly - the `author.php` template is too late in this instance.

Comment: It's a PHP thing with variable scopes. You can get around it with the `global` keyword, but really having the definition be in `author.php` is much more simple of a solution because since it is already limited to the author template, you don't need to use the `is_author()` function to test.

Comment: @bosco We're strictly talking the definition of the variable `$curauth`. That has to be done in `author.php`.

Comment: @belinus I see no reason why that logic must be in `author.php`. But the problem here is that no matter where that logic's placed in `author.php`, neither `header.php` nor any function it calls will have access to `$curauth`. If you use the `global` scope, it will only work if you place your logic above `get_header()` in `author.php` - otherwise `header.php` will be interpreted first before `$curauth` is ever declared.

Comment: @belinus Is only working if I set the $curauth in header.php, the problem is that the array error happens, is there any solution?

Comment: The [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Setting_Up_for_Author_Information) has it in `author.php`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to conditionally call [`wp_no_robots()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_no_robots/) (or echo your custom `<meta>` element) in a [`wp_head` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) hook. This has the added benefit of being modular - you could throw it in a plugin instead of performing theme modifications, if desired.

In the instance of an author archive, [`get_queried_object()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) will (usually - setting other query vars can throw this off) return an instance of [`WP_User`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) - the same type of object that [`get_userdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) returns.

```
function wpse261293_noindex_subscriber_profiles() {
  // Ignore non-author-archive content
  if( !is_author() )
    return;

  // Get a WP_User object for the author
  $author = get_queried_object();

  // If 'subscriber' is the author's only role, print a nofollow robots meta element
  if( count( $author->roles ) === 1 && in_array( 'subscriber', $author->roles ) )
    wp_no_robots(); // Alternately, replace this with echo( 'your_custom_meta_element' )
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse261293_noindex_subscriber_profiles' );
```

If you or another plugin have custom user roles which could be granted to subscribers, you may need to alter the logic to account for them - potentially by checking if the author simply does not have administrator, editor, contributor, etc. roles.

Comment: The function is echoing in all author pages, not just in the subscribers

Comment: Well that's weird - did you remove the meta-element you were working on from `header.php` before-hand? You could try replacing `wp_no_robots()` with `echo( '<!-- wpse261293 TEST -->' );` to make sure that the robots tag you're seeing is actually coming from the hook in my answer.

Comment: That works for me, nice one